# Append or create and new Dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, key, key-value

I have two files one with `Keys` only and one with `Key and Value`. I am trying to append the key file with corresponding values or create a new output file with key and corresponding value.  Individually I can read the key and value perfectly. I am having trouble in merging the two together. The code below it shows the end values together. I understand that first for loop is ending and then second for loop is starting. That is the reason I get only the last item from key and value file. How do I solve this in simple way ?

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('input1', 'r') as classified_data:
    with open('input2', 'r') as edge_data:    
        with open('output', 'w') as outfile:  
        for row in classified_data:
            col = row.strip().split()
            key = col[0], col[1]
            #print key
        for row in edge_data:
            col = row.strip().split()           
            value = col[2], col[3], col[4]
            #print value
        print {key:value}
```

Input1:

```
3545 4945
3545 2814
3545 5045
3545 4921
3545 2564
3545 2311
3545 1644
3545 3820
3545 388
3545 928
3545 3626
3545 1191
3545 4243
3545 3867
3545 701
```

Input2:

```
4945 3545 57 250848.0 4400.84210526 
3584 292 5 1645.0 329.0 
4824 2283 5 16867.0 3373.4 
1715 55 1 681.0 681.0 
5409 2822 2 3221.0 1610.5 
4955 656 6 3348.0 558.0 
4157 487 1 201.0 201.0 
2628 309 2 2466.0 1233.0 
3929 300 2 1742.0 871.0 
3730 489 12 10706.0 892.166666667 
5474 2336 2 1533.0 766.5 
3877 716 10 45028.0 4502.8 
3058 3045 12 17328.0 1444.0
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you associate the lines of the first file with those of the second. Does line 1 on the first file relate to line 1 of the second file, and so on?

Comment: @goncalopp No. I have to search the key pair from file1 with the key pair in files2 and pull the corresponding value from file2 and print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to do a number of lookups in the data from the second file, using keys obtained from the first file. If that's the case, and assuming that you can fit the second file in memory, then I suggest reading the second file into a dictionary with keys that you'll be using for the lookup:

```
edges = {}
with open('input2', 'r') as edge_data:    
    for row in edge_data:
        col = row.strip().split()
        edges[col[0], col[1]] = col[2], col[3], col[4]
```

Then to do the queries, read through the first file and print out the matches:

```
with open('input1', 'r') as classified_data:
    for row in classified_data:
        key = tuple(row.strip().split())
        print key, edges.get(key)
```

If you want to match the keys based on either order of the numbers, then you can modify this last piece of code to try both combinations explicitly:

```
with open('input1', 'r') as classified_data:
    for row in classified_data:
        a, b = row.strip().split()
        print a, b, edges.get((a, b), edges.get((b, a)))
```

Comment: Error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dict_one.py", line 12, in <module>
    print key, edges[key]
KeyError: ('3545', '4945')`  The key is present in both the files

Comment: Hm, the KeyError would seem to indicate otherwise. Are you sure that key is present in the "input2" file? In the example inputs that you posted in your question, that key is in fact not present in input2. (Actually nothing starting with 3545 is present in input2!)

Comment: I just updated the code in my answer to avoid throwing a KeyError, but it might just print out `None` now for all your keys.

Comment: The file is about million rows and I cannot post all the lines :) I have posted 15 rows from each file. Let me change the input sequence so that at-least one pair matches.

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful!

Comment: So in the updated input2 it appears that the columns of the two key numbers have been reversed. Is this always going to be true?

Comment: yes it could be any position but they both are key as pair.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61475/discussion-between-sitz-blogz-and-lmjohns3).

Answer (score 0):

what about collecting the keys and values in a list of tuples and in the end, zipping them to a dict?

```
from collections import defaultdict

keys = []
values = []

with open('input1', 'r') as classified_data:
    # with open('output', 'w') as outfile:  
    for row in classified_data:
        col = row.strip().split()
        keys.append((col[0], col[1]))
        # print key
with open('input2', 'r') as edge_data:    
    for row in edge_data:
        col = row.strip().split()           
        values.append((col[2], col[3], col[4]))
        # print value

print dict(zip(keys,values))
```

Comment: then I didn't get your question... I thought you want to put the first line of input1 as key and the first line of input2 as value of the new dictionary.